# How to send test data to Logstash for troubleshooting

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I'm using a server with a properly configured ELK stack, but filebeat is failing to send input to the given port I have configured at both ends (logstash input port, the same as the filebeat.yml host).

Since I see the filebeat log producing the following entry:

> Dec 28 01:25:02 [servername] /usr/bin/filebeat[50873]:
>   transport.go:125: SSL client failed to connect with: dial tcp
>   ELK_SERVER_IP:PORT: i/o timeout

I am inclined to think that it is due to a firewall in the middle.

I would like to send customized/handmade data to the given port, for purpouses, both of sending test data to populate my test instance (running in a virtual-box) and testing my firewall theory. Can I use telnet? Is there some command to send? Does logstash requires special configuration to support this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had a permissions issue. The user running the logstash daemon, did not have permissions to the cert file in the configuration (indicated here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04). Never saw that comming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to use encrypted communication between filebeat and logstash, a simple telnet connection won't work.

If you want to back up and test the general connectivity to the port, I would shutdown logstash, setup a simple 'nc' server on the same port, and then you could try to connect from the client (with telnet or nc).

If that works, you might also crank up debugging on filebeat, which could give you more information.